# Best Practice for Stylesheet If statements in SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm starting to work with SPFx and have the following code:

```
public render(): void {
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css');
var abc = (this.properties.showFb) ? styles.show: styles.hide;
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
<div class="${ styles.sizing } ">
  <a class="fab fa-facebook-square ${ styles.faCustom } ${ abc }" style="color: #40599A;" href="https://www.facebook.com">&nbsp;</a>
  <a class="fab fa-twitter ${ styles.faCustom }" style="color: #1DA1F2;" href="https://www.twitter.com">&nbsp;</a>
  <a class="fab fa-instagram ${ styles.faCustom } ${ styles.instagram }" style="" href="https://www.instagram.com"></a>
  ${escape(this.properties.description)}
</div>
`;
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this portion?

```
var abc = (this.properties.showFb) ? styles.show: styles.hide;
```

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to theChrisKent for confirming that 
`var abc = (this.properties.showFb) ? styles.show: styles.hide;` 
is an acceptable way to handle showing/hiding pieces of my code.